# History table design with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have inherited another project that has a history table.  The tables look like this and are in a no delete SQL Server database.

NOTE: Each table is a "pair" of tables.  Each table has a parent and child table.

**tBooks**

```
id
created_at
updated_at
deleted_at (if this has a date, entire record and all children considered deleted)
```

**tBookDetails**

```
id
book_id (FK to tBooks id column)
... (related book data)
created_at
updated_at
deleted_at
```

Throw in the mix any relations to this table, for instance and how ActiveRecord would handle their relationships in Rails.

**tCheckouts**

```
id
created_at
updated_at
deleted_at
```

**tCheckoutDetails**

```
id
checkout_id
book_id
user_id
due_at
... (related checkout data)
created_at
updated_at
deleted_at
```

Basically the tBooks table has one record with multiple children records in the tBookDetails table.  The only "active" record is any record that has NULL in the deleted_at table of the children.  It kind of reminds me of a wikipedia type database where there is a history of changes per record, but only 1 active record at a time.

Currently to retrieve the active record, the database contains a SQL Server view that looks like:

```
SELECT bd.*
FROM tBooks b
INNER JOIN tBookDetails bd ON bd.book_id = b.id
WHERE bd.deleted_at IS null
  AND b.deleted_at IS null
```

How would Ruby on Rails approach a database like this?

Comment: Rails example pretty close to this: http://strikingly.github.io/blog/2015/09/14/Simple-rails-history-pattern-ActiveRecord/

Answer (score 0):

Very simple to do in Rails, you'll need [associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html), [scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) and the non-standard table name will require you to [override the table name](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#overriding-the-naming-conventions)